# Cannot browse or download https sites

Tags: server, https

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 Server on VMWare.
I can do apt-get update and install using https.
However when the site is https it Times Out.
I have also tested this using lynx browsing https://www.yahoo.com
It also times out.  What is wrong?

Comment: A lot of services will block unrecognised (or uncommon) agents. You may need to spoof the browser agent string to look like you're sending a request from Chrome or Safari.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Server which only has CLI.  I tried to browse from another computer same network and I could browse fine.  Ubuntu Server only has CLI that's why I am using Lynx browser.

Comment: Regardless, the comment still stands. A lot of services — such as Yahoo! or Bing or Rakuten or Amazon — will block requests from tools that do not pass a user agent string that matches expectations. I've seen this with a number of sites and the solution is always to spoof the UserAgent string and, if you're accessing a Japanese or Korean site/service, cookies as well.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I resolve this? I am not obviously using Chrome or Safari.  I am using the CLI like apt-get or lynx text based browser.